# Alternate routes based on construction with Google Maps API Directions Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

Is it possible to use Google Directions API in conjunction with construction data? For instance, if I had a map that I entered a bunch of construction areas, can Google Directions then be made aware of these and to avoid them, providing a better route?

Comment: Obviously not. If it was possible it would be a gift to spammers. ie: put fake construction sites on all alternate roads, except the one that passes in front of your store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (currently) to input "roadblocks".  See this feature request (star it if you want to support it):

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=214